# Are account names (kSecAttrAccount) encrypted in iOS keychain?

Tags: ios, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

Apple's [GenericKeychain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/Classes_KeychainItemWrapper_m.html) example saves a username and password in the iOS keychain.  It does this using `kSecAttrAccount` for the username, and `kSecValueData` for the password.

Are all data items placed in the keychain encrypted, so including the `kSecAttrAccount`/username in this example?

I'm asking because I don't want account names to be exposed.

Comment: Have you looked in the app document folder?

Comment: Yes, I've looked @Undo, but it's not very clear. I don't want to guess with things like the keychain.

Comment: Have you found an answer for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `kSecAttr` for the username it will be encrypted.

> The attributes associated with a keychain item depend on the class of the item; the item classes most used by applications ... are Internet passwords and generic passwords. As you might expect, Internet passwords include attributes for such things as security domain, protocol type, and path. The passwords or other secrets stored as keychain items are encrypted.

(see ["Structure of a Keychain"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html))

As you use `kSecAttrAccount`, which can only be used with the classes `kSecClassInternetPassword` and `kSecClassGenericPassword` (see [Keychain Services Reference @ kSecAttrAccount](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html)), the account name will be encrypted.